# Set a timeout limit for Google Maps, and how to test it?

Tags: javascript, jquery, google-maps

Is anyone out there using a timeout on with the google maps API?  I have a google map which gets loaded from the fusion table.  My client wants me to resort to a different solution if the maps doesn't load in x seconds.

I tried using a javascript timeout function and $(document).ready, but found that the jquery ready was firing before the map was even rendered to the screen.

With all that said... does any one know a way to force a timeout to test some of the solutions that are available.

Thanks,
Andy

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Could you use the `tilesloaded` event? The code would look something like this:

```
// set up the map and timeout
var map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById("map"), someOptions),
    timeoutSeconds = 4,
    usingMap = false;

function doAlternateStuff() {
    // do whatever the fallback requires
}

// set a timeout and store the reference
var timer = window.setTimeout(doAlternateStuff, timeoutSeconds * 1000);

// now listen for the tilesloaded event
google.maps.event.addListener(map, 'tilesloaded', function() {
    // cancel the timeout
    window.clearTimeout(timer);
    usingMap = true;
    // etc
});
```

Comment: Thanks! I am working with Angular 1, and I apply your answer thereby:
`var timer = $timeout(doAlternateStuff, timeoutSeconds * 1000);
google.maps.event.addListener(map, 'tilesloaded', function() {
    $timeout.cancel(timer);
});`